# Fit a straight line on curve in image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, straight-line-detection

I am trying to detect a straight line on an image containing a not so straight line using OpenCV python.

For example in this image, we can see there is a somewhat horizontal line.

[image: Raw image]

I have tried using Hough lines but only small segments are detected. Do you know how I should proceed for this?
Ideally I would have a detected line as follows:
[image: detected line]

Comment: Which straight line do you want to detect there? The "somewhat straight horizontal line" isnt straight at all. Can you define the requirements and the goal? Maybe show the desired result.

Comment: Try 1. Threshold 2. Use RANSAC line "fitting"

Comment: by the way, that polar transform is horribly botched. someone "threw" the points, which is wrong and impossible to "fix up". they need to be "pulled". if you're wondering why there are gaps and noise, that's why. simply use OpenCV's polar warp. that does it right.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am not sure I can do it with this function, with the image I have, it is one column per angle

Comment: that is precisely what opencv's polar warp is for. perhaps you need to flip/mirror/transpose/rot90 your input... you'll figure it out... or add the source data to your question

Comment: For each white dot, determine if that dot may join in the horizontal line (for example, using PCA etc). This step will reject many unnecessary points.
Then find the horizontal line(for example, using RANSAC).